# HTML vs JSP for partials in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a Single page application using angular & spring. Currently i am using .jsp files for view; but till now i haven't done any jsp related stuff on views. As every JSP is converted to servlet it will decrease the performance compared to HTML.

So my questions are

1 Why not to use plain HTML instead of JSP?

2 Does it have major performance difference?

3 If JSP is recommended then what are advantages?

Answer (score 1):

HTML doesn't allow for dynamic data (i.e pulled from a database)

HTML is static data, unless paired with Javascript (in which you'd have to get the data from post requests, which results in multiple requests to your server which lowers performance).

Yes, there is a performance impact on using JSP but its unavoidable if you want dynamic data, dynamic data requires processing so the other option would just be to do it in angular and getting the data via get requests to your server, but as i said earlier thats multiple requests to your server for no real reason most of the time.

If you're fine with making multiple requests to your server for one page load  then more preferable - I guess - HTML and getting the data through angular hitting the backend API and get the data

Answer (score 1):

> 1 Why not to use plain HTML instead of JSP?

Yes you can use html instead of jsp files if you do not have any dynamic >  data to be appended to the page.e.g you will not be able to use out, >  session, page, expressions and jsp taglibs in html.

> 2 Does it have major performance difference?

Jsp always gets compiled and then it is rendered as a HTML page but if you have a html page to be rendered , it does not need that processing at server side and can be rendered way faster than jsp.

> 3 If JSP is recommended then what are advantages?

Jsp is recommended if you want to add dynamic data to your page, like get data from session object, display model objects. But if do not want all these and want to render a page that hardly changes then it is recommended to use html.

Also if you have angular and web services, you should use angular and ajax calls to render your page.

1. This will reduce the server processing time to display view.
2. You can make multiple ajax calls to load your data async in parallel this does not force your server to load all data first and then render page.
3. Page loading time would reduce since we can perform data calls in asyn manner in parallel.